# Disable TeamFoundation addin in Excel programmatically

Tags: vsto, openxml, ribbon, excel-addins

The requirement is to disable all the ribbon tabs and add a new custom tabs. When I use

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
```

in my Ribbon.xml it disables all the tabs. But I can see the Team tab(TeamFoundation addin) and when I select a table in the excel it also shows up Design tab.

How can I disable all these tabs which are not done

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
```

in the Ribbon.xml?

Thanks
Kiru

Comment: Found a way by deleting the registry entry for TeamFoundation addin, but looking some other better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ignored this problem because only the developers and testers had access to TFS so the TeamFoundation addin ribbon is not available for end users in my case.